# How to convert .txt file to html.XML file via VBA?

Tags: xml, vba

we have files in .txt format that need to be converted to HTML-base.XML file, and the .txt file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBoxData> 
    <CategoriesAndProducts>   
        <Categories>RetailCADTerm Investment30 DaysLess $5 Million</Categories>
    <Products>  
        <Product>2.30</Product>
    </Products> 
    </CategoriesAndProducts>  

    <CategoriesAndProducts> 
        <Categories>RetailCADTerm Investment30 DaysGreater $5 Million</Categories>
    <Products>  
        <Product>2.15</Product>
    </Products> 
    </CategoriesAndProducts> 

    <CategoriesAndProducts> 
        <Categories>RetailUSDTerm Investment30 DaysLess $5 Million</Categories>
    <Products>  
        <Product>2.06</Product>
    </Products> 
    </CategoriesAndProducts> 
</ListBoxData>
```

How to convert this .txt file to html.xml via VBA?

Thanks!

(Note: below is a script that might help on brain-storming but it does not convert to HTML-base.XML):

```
PrivaPrivate Sub ConvertFile_Click()
Dim s As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
s = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="TXT File,*.txt")
Workbooks.Open Filename:=s
s = Replace(s, ".txt", ".xml")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=s, _
        FileFormat:=xlXMLSpreadsheet, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, 
CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: xml file are just text files with specific formating, so I would just suggest that you rename them from *.txt to *.xml?

Comment: It actually works. I think this can be the solution. Thank you!